# Converting Python Dict containing list of lists into pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
names = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']
marriageDates = ['02-02-1958', '08-07-1969', ['01-21-1973','07-14-1981']]
people = {
    "Name": names,
    "Marriage Date(s)": marriageDates
}
df = pd.DataFrame(people)
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
    Name             Marriage Date(s)
0    Tom                02-02-1958
1   Dick                08-07-1969
2  Harry  [01-21-1973, 07-14-1981]
```

However, I want the output to be:

```
    Name 1st Marriage Date 2nd Marriage Date
0    Tom        02-02-1958                  
1   Dick        08-07-1969                  
2  Harry        01-21-1973        07-14-1981
```

In other words, one of the keys in my dict is a list of lists. Rather than that key populate a column who's entries are lists (as in the last row in the first table), I want the nth elements of that list to be placed in new, adjacent columns (as in the second table). Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: post your expected output

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and your expected output.

Comment: My bad. First time posting. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
import pandas as pd
ordinal = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n,"tsnrhtdd"[(n/10%10!=1)*(n%10<4)*n%10::4])
names = ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry']
marriageDates = ['02-02-1958', '08-07-1969', ['01-21-1973','07-14-1981']]
people = {
    "Name": names,
    "Marriage Date(s)": marriageDates
}
df = pd.DataFrame(people)
marriage_date_df = df['Marriage Date(s)'].apply(pd.Series)
marriage_date_df = marriage_date_df.rename(columns = lambda x :  ordinal(x+1)+' Marriage Date')
result_df = pd.concat([df[["Name"]], marriage_date_df[:]], axis=1)
result_df
```

It gives output:-

```
    Name    1st Marriage Date   2nd Marriage Date
0   Tom     02-02-1958          NaN
1   Dick    08-07-1969          NaN
2   Harry   01-21-1973          07-14-1981
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a surprisingly easy way to do this. I recently found out about it too.

```
df2 = df['Marriage Date(s)'].apply(pd.Series)
pd.concat([df[['Name']], df2], axis=1).rename(columns={0:'1st Marriage Date',1:'2st Marriage Date'})

    Name    1st Marriage Date   2st Marriage Date
0   Tom     02-02-1958  NaN
1   Dick    08-07-1969  NaN
2   Harry   01-21-1973  07-14-1981
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This does the job for the given data -- individuals having no more than two marriage dates, but it does not generalize to a dataset with N marriage dates. Is there a way to generalize your code for this case?

Comment: In your sample data, the three wedding anniversaries for 'Harry' were also split correctly. Does it meet your confirmation?

Comment: If you have more than one wedding anniversary, it's a confirmation that you can.

Comment: I set up and ran multiple wedding anniversaries with multiple people, and they were split correctly.

Comment: Yes, you can manually input the number of wedding anniversary columns if you know the number needed _a priori_. However, I'm not assuming that is the case. I want the columns to be rendered dynamically for a list with any given number of marriages. tuhinsharma121's code accomplishes this, which is why I selected his answer. Your concise answer was much appreciated however, and I used your response in conjunction with his.